# Google Analytics Social Tracking implementation. Is Google's example correct?

Tags: google-analytics, social-media, social-sharing-buttons

The current Google Analytics help page on Social tracking (developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial?hl=es-419) links to this page with an example of the implementation: http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/tracking/javascript/v5/social/facebook_js_async.html

I've followed the example carefully yet social interactions are not registered.
This is the webpage with the non-working setup: http://bit.ly/1dA00dY (obscured domain as per Google's Webmaster Central recommendations for their product forums)

This is the structure of the page:

1. In the :

   1. ga async code copied from the analytics' page
   2. a script tag linking to  stored in the same domain.
   3. the twitter js loading tag
2. In the

   1. the fb-root div
   2. the facebook async loading js including the _ga.trackFacebook(); call
   3. the social buttons afterwards, like so:

      1. (with the proper URL)
      2. Tweet (with the proper handle)

That's it. As far as I can tell, I have implemented it exactly like in the example, but likes and twitts aren't registered.

I have also altered the ga_social_tracking.js to register the social interactions as events, adding the code below. It doesn't work either. What could be wrong?

*Thanks!*

---

Code added to `ga_social_tracking.js`

```
var url = document.URL;
var category = 'Social Media';

/* Facebook */
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, 'Facebook', url]);
});

/* Twitter */
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, 'Twitter', url]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: You may be trying to bind to the events before all the javascript files are loaded.  The calls to `FB.Event.subscribe` and `twttr.events.bind` should be done after the page is loaded.  For example using jquery `$(document).ready(function() {` or the method built into the facebook api: `window.fbAsyncInit = function(){`

I would recommend putting `console.log` calls next to your `_gaq.push` calls to ensure that you can see those functions firing when you push the like button.